# Postgres / SQL::Abstract "Not In Range" Operation

Tags: perl, postgresql

Postgres has some cool range operators for handling ranges:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-range.html

...but doesn't appear to have anything to handle 'not' being in a range.  For instance, the **@>** operator means 'contains element' or 'contains range'.  But equally helpful would be the **!@>** operator, which doesn't seem to exist.

If I'm trying to say "query where date is not in range", is there any solution other than using a conditional expression?  I'm using SQL::Abstract, which doesn't support expressions without using literal SQL, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using NOT BETWEEN date AND date.

Sorry, you may still end up using a SQL literal.

Comment: I'd say this is probably going to be the best answer, although I wish there was a way I could take advantage of those new operators!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. I was a fan of SQL::Abstract several years ago, but have now completely replaced it with SQL::Interp (via DBIx::Simple integration) in my projects. I find it easier to read and write, and it doesn't have any hangups with complex expressions.

Comment: I'll have to check that out.  Unfortunately, I'm pretty deep in SQL::Abstract, but maybe this is a sign that it's time to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way

```
FALSE = INT4RANGE(1,5) @> 5
```